# Play Framework: How do I change active class on route change

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2 for Java and Bootstrap Helper in my project and I want to apply `active` class on sidebar link click. I am using side nav bar for navigation and by default one link is always has `active` class on page load, so thats why in every time only one link is highlighted as a active link, but how to change the `class="active"` on route or link change, is there any way to check the route path is our html scala template file.

Here are my side bar navigation code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
     <li class="active"><a href="/menu1">Menu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="/menu2">Menu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="/menu3">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here are my `routes` file

```
GET    /menu1          com.demo.project.controllers.DemoController.menu1()
GET    /menu2          com.demo.project.controllers.DemoController.menu2()
GET    /menu3          com.demo.project.controllers.DemoController.menu3()
```

Please give me some suggestion on it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got solution for my problem, I am sharing my solution for others too.
Firstly I created a method inside my html scala template file.

```
@activeLink(currentPath:String) = @{
if(request.path.equals(currentPath)) "active"
}
```

Now need to call the above method inside `class` attribute of `anchor` tag.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
 <li class="@activeLink("/menu1")"><a href="/menu1">Menu1</a></li>
 <li class="@activeLink("/menu2")"><a href="/menu2">Menu2</a></li>
 <li class="@activeLink("/menu3")"><a href="/menu3">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my final solution, If some one has another solution or approaching different way for the same so please share those also.