# How to use action as parameter for other action in play 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4, play-templates

I've the following function inside a template:

```
@activeLink(currentPath:String) = @{
    if(request.path.equals(currentPath)) {
        "active"
    }

}
```

( from: [Play Framework: How do I change active class on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296838/play-framework-how-do-i-change-active-class-on-route-change/22297596#22297596) )

Now I want to call it like:

```
@activeLink(@routes.Application.index().url)
```

But I get the following error:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[illegal start of simple expression]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61) ~[na:na]
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:323) ~[na:na]
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39) ~[na:na]
    at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:321) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:113) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
```

What is the proper way to pass an the url to an function inside a template?

Tested with Play 2.4.6 and Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter must be pass without '@' try `@activeLink(routes.Application.index().url)`

Comment: Thank you, sir. Do you know where that is documented? Why is that so?

Comment: You're welcome, '@' character define beggining of scala code interpreting.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates section "Syntax: the magic ‘@’ character"