# How can I change Bootstrap sidebar class active status using PlayFramework?

Tags: javascript, html, playframework

I am using Play Framework 2.2.5 for Java and Bootstrap helper in my project and I want to apply active class on sidebar link click. How to change the `class="active"` on route or link change?

```
<div class="list-group sideBarStyles" id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">  
   <li><a href="@routes.Reports.getReportHome()"  class="list-group-item">REPORTS</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@routes.Timesheets.showSelectPage()"  class="list-group-item">TIMESHEET</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@routes.MonthlyReports.viewUploadedReports()"  class="list-group-item">MONTHLY REPORTS</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@routes.DailyReconciliations.drViewOptions(0,"reportingBusinessDate","desc","SUBMITTED","VIEW")"  class="list-group-item">RECONCILIATION</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="@routes.InvoiceInventory.showDownloadPage()" class="list-group-item">INVOICE INVENTORY</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@routes.InvoiceInventory.showUploadPageForHeadOffice()" class="list-group-item">INVOICE UPLOAD</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer answer of similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296838/play-framework-how-do-i-change-active-class-on-route-change

Comment: i have been trying that solution but it is not working for my sidebar navigation.

Comment: <li class="@activeLink("routes.Timesheets.showSelectPage()")"><a href="@routes.Timesheets.showSelectPage()"  class="list-group-item">TIMESHEET</a> </li>

Comment: @activeLink(currentPath:String) = @{
if(request.path.equals(currentPath)) "active"
}

Comment: please tell me where I did mistake in above code?

Comment: Above stackoverflow solution should work. Try with simpler sidebars and debug your code putting breakpoints in method for toggling active class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method inside you HTML Scala template and add this code:

```
@activeLink(currentPath:String) = @{
  if(request.path.equals(currentPath)) "active"
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<li><a class="@activeLink("/reports")" href="/reports" >REPORTS</a> </li>
```

See this for more information: [Play Framework: How do I change active class on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296838/play-framework-how-do-i-change-active-class-on-route-change)

Comment: can we send string parameter like below?

Comment: <li><a class="@activeLink("/reports<li><a class="@activeLink("/reports")" href="<li><a class="@activeLink("/reports")" href="/reports" >REPORTS</a> </li>" >REPORTS</a> </li>")" href="/reports" >REPORTS</a> </li>

Comment: @activeLink("@activeLink("/reports")")

Comment: why I am passing like this is, Method having dynamic parameters also in url.

Comment: You can only pass a string parameter to @activeLink() so use routes.InvoiceInventory.showDownloadPage().toString() and it should work

Comment: @activeLink(routes.InvoiceInventory.showDownloadPage().toString())